# Sequelize - Trying to fetch associated objects using 'include' for a belongsToMany relationship

Tags: node.js, express, sequelize.js

I have a model called Experience, which has a belongsToMany association with the model Category through ExperienceCategory table. For an experience, I'm trying to fetch the Experience details with the Categories it belongs to. Some I'm using `include: [{model: model.Category}]` to achieve this. Now, the association is working and it is fetching the categories correctly, but the problem is that it's giving multiple objects of the Experience model, one for each Category. Below are some excerpts from my code:

```
model.Experience.findAll({
  include: [
    {
      model: model.Category
    }
  ]
}).then(experiences => {
  res.json({experiences: experiences});
})
```

This is how I have defined my associations:
experience.js:

```
Experience.belongsToMany(models.Category, {
  through: 'ExperienceCategory',
  foreignKey: 'experience_id',
});
```

category.js

```
Category.belongsToMany(models.Experience, {
  through: 'ExperienceCategory',
  foreignKey: 'category_id'
});
```

The response to the above query is:

```
{
  "experiences": [
    {
      "id": 23,
      "title": "Some title",
      "notes": "These are notes",
      "base_amount": 2000,
      "is_disabled": false,
      "is_deleted": false,
      "createdAt": "2019-05-27T12:24:06.736Z",
      "updatedAt": "2019-07-23T11:20:23.695Z",
      "Categories.id": 4,
      "Categories.name": "Trekking",
      "Categories.is_disabled": false,
      "Categories.is_deleted": false,
      "Categories.createdAt": "2019-05-14T11:07:40.287Z",
      "Categories.updatedAt": "2019-05-14T11:07:40.287Z",
      "Categories.ExperienceCategory.experience_id": 23,
      "Categories.ExperienceCategory.category_id": 4,
      "Categories.ExperienceCategory.createdAt": "2019-05-27T12:24:06.806Z",
      "Categories.ExperienceCategory.updatedAt": "2019-05-27T12:24:06.806Z"
    },
    {
      "id": 23,
      "title": "Some title",
      "notes": "These are notes",
      "base_amount": 2000,
      "is_disabled": false,
      "is_deleted": false,
      "createdAt": "2019-05-27T12:24:06.736Z",
      "updatedAt": "2019-07-23T11:20:23.695Z",
      "Categories.id": 5,
      "Categories.name": "Adventure",
      "Categories.is_disabled": false,
      "Categories.is_deleted": false,
      "Categories.createdAt": "2019-05-14T11:07:40.287Z",
      "Categories.updatedAt": "2019-05-14T11:07:40.287Z",
      "Categories.ExperienceCategory.experience_id": 23,
      "Categories.ExperienceCategory.category_id": 5,
      "Categories.ExperienceCategory.createdAt": "2019-05-27T12:24:06.806Z",
      "Categories.ExperienceCategory.updatedAt": "2019-05-27T12:24:06.806Z"
    }
  ]
}
```

You can see that for Experience ID 23 is repeated twice because there are two different Categories. Can I get the Categories in an array instead?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Let say you have in your `Experience` model file the following association:

```
Experience.belongsToMany(models.Category, { through: 'ExperienceCategory', as: 'categories' });
```

You will then need to do the following to have a list of category in your experience request:

```
models.Experience.findAll({
 include: [
  { model: models.Category, as: 'categories' }
 ]
}).then(experiences => {
 res.json({experiences: experiences});
})
```

Comment: Thanks. I have edited my question with the way I have defined the associations. I did try what you suggested, where I changed `through: 'ExperienceCategory'` to `through: 'categories'` but that gave me an error. And by providing an alias, I still get multiple objects for Experience.

Comment: Well, it works perfectly for me, I don't know how to help you more without testing your code

Comment: I have a small repo on github where i'm using sequelize, you can check if you want: https://github.com/SebastienBtr/private-imdb-api